# Samba client error: nt_status_request_not_accepted

Tags: samba, smb, winexe

The programs which use the samba connection underneath sometimes throw the error `nt_status_request_not_accepted` after logon.

There are threads about this error on the Inernet since 2005, but there is no solution or hint yet.

What could be the cause of this error?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Some other samba connection is likely still open.
If this is the programming issue, check that all the connections are being properly closed.
Otherwise the reboot might help.